# JSON milliseconds date to java date

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, gson

i'm consuming a rest api , and i have this issue

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator '0'
```

basically I am using Gson to convert Json to my Class

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyResponse myResponse = gson.fromJson(responseService.getNumber(id), MyResponse.class);
```

But i have a date in my json like this

```
 "date": 1375412400000
```

How can i transform to my model class in date? To convert and show 02/25/2018 for example?

MyResponse.class

```
public class MyResponse {


    List<Dados> dados;


    public List<Dados> getDados() {
        return dados;
    }

    public void setDados(List<Dados> dados) {
        this.dados = dados;
    }


}
```

ResponseService.class

```
public interface ResponseService {

    @GetMapping("/search/rg/{rg}")
    String getDados(@PathVariable("rg") String rg);

}
```

Dados.Class

```
public class Dados {



@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="dd/MM/yyyy",locale = "pt-BR", timezone = "Brazil/East")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
Date data;




String codigo;

String estado;


String  cidade;

String oriundo;


...gets and setters




}
```

Comment: Where is the full code? You are using variables that are not present.

Comment: responseService.getNumber(id) is only mapping url to get rest service. My class with date is 
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="dd/MM/yyyy",locale = "pt-BR", timezone = "Brazil/East")
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 Date date;

Comment: Please provide a valid MCVE... and edit your question if you provide more info...

Comment: updated   with the classes

Comment: `@JsonFormat` doesn't belong to Gson. Looks like you are mixing Jackson and Gson.

Comment: I have found the solution in this  [blog](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/String-Date-Parsing-with-GSON-UTC-Time-Zone).

Comment: @ErickVinicius Please write up an Answer here to your own Question, so that you may accept it to mark this Question as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
First i had to set my date

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
```

After i had to create a class to deserialize the date

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer; 
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

  @Override
  public Date deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1, 
  JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
    String date = element.getAsString();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    try {
        return formatter.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to parse Date due to:", e);
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

then i used my class applying in gsonbuilder

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
```